# Trouble using import in python after trying to install pyserial

Tags: python, macos, terminal, filesystems

I had a project where I was trying to communicate between Arduino and Python so I attempted to install pyserial from Terminal. It didn't seem to work and I tried again with easy_install to no avail and then pip to no avail. Nothing seemed to work so I tried to install it on windows and it worked with no problems so I gave up trying to work with pyserial on my mac. HOWEVER, now any python project on my mac that uses ANY imported library encounters a problem. To double check this, I went back to a previously functional project where I used numpy, and when I ran it *without changing anything*, I got this terminal message:

```
/var/folders/4r/d5h66_596g3_bfq56prs1f100000gn/T/Cleanup\ At\ Startup/DragonCurve-482948663.465.py.command ; exit;
nbp-30-74:~ warrenbrodsky$ /var/folders/4r/d5h66_596g3_bfq56prs1f100000gn/T/Cleanup\ At\ Startup/DragonCurve-482948663.465.py.command ; exit;
> /Users/warrenbrodsky/Documents/Python/DragonCurve.py(23)<module>()
-> import numpy as np
(Pdb)
```

and then nothing. I don't really have any experience with terminal, or managing filesystems or anything like that. I searched the web, but I don't even know where to begin, what or how to check things, etc. Any help would be super appreciated!

---

edit: here is my [DragonCurve code](https://github.com/nerraw/nerraw.github.io/blob/master/dragonplot.py), if you would like to take a look. The problem seems to be when I try to import though, as I encounter this issue in all my projects that use import.

Comment: It seems you ended up in a PDB shell because a breakpoint got triggered. Just to be clear: You didn't deliberately set a PDB breakpoint yourself somewhere, did you?

Comment: No. I'm not sure what that even is...any idea how to track it down/get rid of it?

edit: to be clear, I get this (or a similar message) whenever I run *any* python script that imports *any* library.

Comment: It's a debugging shell that pauses the execution of your program, and allows you to inspect the environment, similar to the interactive Python interpreter. What code is at / around line `23` in `/Users/warrenbrodsky/Documents/Python/DragonCurve.py`? If there is a line similar to `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`, remove it and try again.

Comment: The first 20 lines or so is comments, line 23 is simply "import numpy as np." I've never used the python debugger library before and this problem occurs in all my projects that use "import."  :(

Comment: Well, you can resume execution of your program if you type `c` (followed by `<return>`) in that prompt, but that's not really a solution :-/ Someone or something added a breakpoint in some place (could have been your IDE, caused by a shortcut you accidentally pressed).

Comment: Well I guess that works, then. That's....mildly annoying. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest to [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) your codebase for `pdb.set_trace()` - if you don't find the breakpoint there, you might need to widen the search to Python files in your home directory, or even your entire system.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: I found where I was getting trouble. It *did* turn out to be a setting in my IDE after all. I'm still not sure how it got changed; perhaps something changed it when I was trying to install pyserial.